# How can I export an Angular Material table to a specific directory?

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 8. I have a table made with Angular Material (mat-table) and I can export it as an xls file using [mat-table-exporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mat-table-exporter). When I export, the file ends up in my downloads folder, but I want to export it to a specific directory such as **Y:exports/today/filename**. If this is not possible, I would at least like to create a folder if it does not exist such as **today/filename**

How can I specify directories of drives in my xls export?

Here is my html code:

```
  <div class="export-container">
     <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="exporter.exportTable('xlsx',
     {fileName:'xls_export' + searchFlightInput + '_' + selectedDate})"> Export as xlsx</button>
   </div>

  <mat-table matTableExporter [dataSource]="dataSource" #exporter="matTableExporter" class="mat-elevation-z8"
    id="materialTable">

    <!-- ACSP Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="acsp">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ACSP </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.acsp}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- year Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="year">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Year </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.year}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible, since the package is using **File-save** dependency which by default process ur data as a Blob stream and the saving is handled by the browser to store in the default download path ...

[File-Saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver)